# How do you use Javascript to get HttpContext.Current.Application in aspx .Net?

Tags: asp.net

After a user logs into my website they store a string in the application context like this:

HttpContext.Current.Application[myString] =  CurrentValue;

How can I access this variable from a javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know i could use a hidden variable as a holder and then find it with my javascript but I would rather just access the app Context from the javascript - Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly from Javascript. HttpContext.Current is on the server, so you either use a hidden field and assign it in your web page code or use an ajax call to get the value that you want

EDITED

You can create a webpage that uses an empty master page. The code that you would add on that webpage would be `Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.Application["myVar"])` and then read the text it prints within the ajax call. Give it a shot and if you find out any problem lt me know

Comment: I understand how to write Ajax but I am not sure how to write the .cs/aspx part of this ( I usually program mvc)
 Can you help me with the C# part of this? Would you make a [web method]??
I know this is the code with in the c#
HttpContext.Current.Application[myString]  as string

Comment: this is the right answer but I could use an example: it would be cool if some one would write a sample ajax request to a sample aspx.cs correspondent

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful and smart

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a web services file to your project in 'Web References', create your Web Method in that file and then consume the web method with a javascript call.

A very clear and easy to understand tutorial is located [here](http://www.semenoff.dk/en/Code-Corner/ASP.Net.AJAX/WebService-From-JavaScript.aspx) (with example code).